# more than one text separator style per template in joomla 3.0

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0, joomla-module

Let me first explain what I am trying to do.
In joomla 3.0  I have created a Menu_Item_Text_Separator override for my template http://docs.joomla.org/Help30:Menus_Menu_Item_Text_Separator. It seems as though joomla will only recognize one default Text separator per template which is ok if you just want the one. but I ideally would like to have the choice of selecting the custom one in my template folder as well as the default one that joomla recognizes. To inform you this is what I have done to make it happen.

1. in my template I have a folder named html which had a folder called mod_menu inside it.
2. In the mod_menu folder I have the .php files called:

default_separator.php
custom_separator.php

1. I then go into menu manager and edit the menu item for which I want to display a text separator for.
2. I then go to 'template style' http://docs.joomla.org/Help30:Menus_Menu_Item_Text_Separator and look for my custom style. but I only can choose the default one.

So i wonder if this is way that joomla works that you can only have one default per template. but is it possible to have more than one?

any advice most welcome.

regards

w9914420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this got too long for a comment.

Okay let's start from the beginning.  Templates have a set of parameters defined in the templateDetails.xml file. A template style is simple a record containing the information about a template and the array of parameter options you have selected.  You can make as many template styles as you want for a given template Each one has its own name.  In the menu you can select any of the styles and assign it to a menu item.  ....

What you are talking about has nothing to do with template styles. You are talking about using a layout override for mod_menu. Because  you are using a file with the same name as a core layout file you should get a 1:1 replacement.

From what I understand of what you want to do, you should instead make a new named replacemen both for default_separator and for default.php.  THat's because the alternative layout field is going to look for a replacement for default.php say yourname.php and then in that replacement when you load a template called separator it is automatically going to look for yourname_separator rather than default_separator because it assumes you are appending the _separator to the base name.  If you do this it has some advantages such as you will be able to make a more complex layout and it will allow you to load different sub layouts conditionally for example.

Comment: Hi Elin, Thanks again for your help. I have gone through your notes and implemented your strategy. Unfortunately I seem to be getting only the option to use the _separator that I specified in my template. I am unable to create alternative default_separator files. I do wonder if my version of Joomla 3 is at fault. Is there any chance that you could specify to which version of joomla this works in. Thanks Elin you been very informative - regards -w9914420

Comment: What is the name of the file where you are storing the override you want to use only sometimes?

Comment: the name of the file is called logix_separator.php and resides in the mod_menu override folder of my template

Comment: Do you have a logix.php file?

Comment: yes i do, I have a php file called logix.php. This file was created by duplicating default.php and renaming it to logix.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are confusing template styles with the style for menu module. Unless you have a parameter in your template that specifies the choice of a mod_menu layout a template style is not going to help you.Go to he module manager and pick the module you want to apply the style to. Use the field to select the layout you want.  Or if it is a css style use the style option.   It could also be that what you really want is to apply module chrome. THat do can be done by editing the module.   If you want to have the same menu with different layouts or styles you'll probably want to make additional modules for that menu.

Comment: my apologies for not being clear in my question but I was not referring to Module Alternative Layouts or module chrome. In particular my questions is in regards to menu items and the 'template style' option located on the right hand side (see link)  http://docs.joomla.org/Help30:Menus_Menu_Item_Text_Separator. I should have asked if the template style is limited to one default style per template or is it possible to create a custom ones also.

Comment: here is a screenshot of my statement: http://bromel.com/menu%20item.JPG - thanks ;)

Comment: also I found this http://docs.joomla.org/Template_style - according to the article it seems you can either use the default one of your joomla installation or the one which you have in your template. I wanted to create an alternative template style as well as having a default template style for my template.

Comment: You can have as many template styles as you want for a template.

Comment: Hi Elin, Is they any chance you can explain how this is done in joomla 2.5 or 3. since I am difficulty in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I had a rethink of what i was trying to do. What I was trying todo could not be achieved through the method I hoped - creating a template for that one text separator would not be practical although I have now discovered how to feed template parameter values into layout overrides.

Thank you Elin for your time

regards w9914420